# Jquery mindate on datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

so i have this jquery function:

```
$("#dynamic_admin_add_event_time").on("focus", ".dateEvent", function () {

  $(this).datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: true,
    minDate: 0,
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
  });
});
```

Where the function is called every time a text input with the class dateEvent on the table is clicked, the datepicker appeared just fine and let me pick dates, the problem is that it doesn't set the minDate property, as i can still select the date before today, where i want to limit the starting date to today.

Can you guys help me with this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`minDate:0` means today if you want to select before today that you can give date before today like `minDate:'2017/08/07',`

Comment: No, i want to select the date from today and onwards, and want to disable the date before today.

Comment: Ok you set this value `minDate:'-1970/01/01',` for set disable before today

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i was using bootstrap datepicker instead of jquery datepicker, my bad

```
        $(this).datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: true,
        minDate: moment(),
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
    });
```

works just as i wanted